# Can i install jenkins plugin into hudson?

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I've opted for Hudson's latest version 3.2.0 over jenkins cos of its ease of use. But still jenkins rules with its features given through numerous plug-ins support. Is it possible to install jenkins's plugin into hudson since both have .hpi plugin types? and I have even tried installing few plugins surprisingly it works at hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. It all depends on the plugin. If the plugin was built using Jenkins/Hudson core when they were still the same thing, it will work. If it relies on new Jenkins' features added since the split, it won't work.

Other than looking for compatibility notices from the developer/maintainer on the plugin wiki page, your only other option is to try it